# Shell script help to post local and external ip of my laptop

Tags: shell, http-post, wget, http-get

I am not sure how to user wget can some one help me with the shell script to post local and external ip of the laptop to an external website? ( both GET and POST methods )

Comment: Can you give us an example of how you would like it to work OR that you can do 'this-and-that' in other contexts and you would like this GET/POST to work the same way. For me, it is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp
ifconfig  | grep "inet addr" | fgrep -v 127.0.0.1 | tr ':' " " | awk '{print $3;}'
```